# 7-Limit tuned 12 tones?

Tags: chords, just-intonation, sevenths

I tried to tune the 12 tones differently to gain more harmony. Rather than equal temperament or just intonation, I picked 7-limit tuning. Here're the tones:

```
    C = 1/1
    C♯ = 21/20
    D = 10/9
    D♯/E♭ = 7/6
    E = 5/4
    F = 4/3
    F♯/G♭ = 7/5
    G = 3/2
    A♭ = 14/9
    A = 5/3
    A♯ = 7/4
    C♭ = 28/15
```

This places the tones in a 3×2×2 grid, and approximates 12-TET well. (Like just intonation does in a 4×3 grid)

My questions are:

1. Is G major chord out of tune in this tuning?
2. Does B mean C♭?
3. Are C7 chord and F7 chord enough to have a chord progression?
4. What is the name of D♯-F♯-A♯-C chord?

Comment: 4. Cm7b5 is one name. But not with those note names, just the sound.

Comment: @Tim -- I might be more inclined to call that an **Ebm6** (or possibly a **D#m6**); respelling needed in any case....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No.  The B is 56:45 above the G, which is rather lower than a just major third at 5:4.  It's about 8 cents low, which is less of a difference than the difference between the just major third and the equal tempered major third.  That might be acceptable.  But the ratio between G and D, after adjusting the octave, is 40:27 rather than 3:2, which is in my opinion unusable as a consonant perfect fifth.
2. Yes.
3. I don't understand this question.
4. I'll leave this for others to argue about.

I'll also note that with most attempts to tune a keyboard to "just intonation" some intervals are too dissonant to be useful as a perfect fifth.  The E to B interval here, for example,

Comment: 3. I mean whether it's possible to have chord progression such as I - V - vi - IV? The only harmonic seventh chords are C7 and F7.

Comment: @DannyuNDos I wrote this answer having read the question carelessly and thinking that you were using 9:8 for D.  I do not think the G-to-D fifth is useable if D is 10:9.  I've edited the answer accordingly.