# Attempt to make Jazz chord progression on 7-Limit tuning

Tags: chords, chord-progressions, jazz, just-intonation, sevenths

This is a sequel to [this question.](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/90893/53617) Refer to it for the just ratio of the tones.

Being septimal, I thought it could be used for Jazz. The chord progression I made is (Based on C):

**CM7 - F♯ø7 - FM7 - G**, repeated.

Is there a name for this particular chord progression? (Like C - G - Am - F is refered as 'The 4 Chords'?)

Is there any song based on this chord progression?

Comment: Not heard of 'the 4 chords' before. I vi IV V is far more often used.

Comment: @Tim, I think he's referring not to a single specific progression, but how most "4 chord progressions" in popular music are built with the 1-4-5-6m in varying orders. E.g. the popularity of the [50s "Stand By Me" chords you mention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_songs_containing_the_50s_progression) is certainly rivaled in pop music by [the "Let It Be" chords he mentioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_songs_containing_the_I%E2%80%93V%E2%80%93vi%E2%80%93IV_progression). Rhythm changes and ragtime are notable exceptions, but I feel like they're not as represented in modern pop.

Comment: @Tim look up Axis of Awesome's 4-chord song video. I've run across "the four chords" pretty often (I-V-vi-IV) under that name, or something to the same effect.

Comment: An example of the progression OP mentions: Chorus of "Love on Top" by Beyoncé.

Comment: @user45266 - seen it, love it. It speaks volumes about the state of pop music these days. Mind you, back in the '60s, it was either 12 bars or I vi IV V, so who are we to criticise..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a term for that exact progression, but it does remind me a bit of [the stomp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stomp_progression) with that #4o7 used to ascend and the dominant being stressed before it repeats.